# How does the 'Cash For Relics' shop work?

Tags: delve-deeper

Some of the maps have tiles with a big sign on them that reads 'cash for relics' and a passive many-eyed beast floating around that must be a shopkeeper or something.

I've stood in the tiles but haven't gotten anything from him.  How do you get relics for cash?  Do you have to be carrying a full load of gold/diamond/mithril?

[image: Cash 4 Relics]

Comment: Perhaps it's the other way around? Maybe he'll give you cash in exchange for your relics

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I'm pretty sure the computer player got a really nice relic from him on the final turn of my last game.  I can try bringing him a chest and see what it is I guess?  Maybe he helps you identify your relics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Cash for Relics" shop will identify and buy relics from you for a cost of two points, similar to the way the Gnomish Bank will bank your gold for a cost of two points.

Comment: It is a terrible, terrible thing to end up selling the Beard of Bees to the Oogler. -7 points with 2-point penalty = ouch.

Comment: @PaulMarshall Oof. Crossing my fingers I don't find that.